# Parse variable stored into a record

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm new to Apex,
and I have a problem this is the situation.

I have a table with employees and email for each of them.
I have a table with `template email (id,subject,body)` and a body is like

> "Hello Mr. &P2_FIRST_NAME."

I try to show the body with the variable parsed...

I can show the "`P2_FIRST_NAME`" with a display only item.

What Should I use to do the job ?

For the moment I use a classic report to show the body because I need to refresh the region. (The body need to be showed when I choose the subject with a select list)

I hope everything is clear with my approximate english !

Thx a lot for your help

Comment: Does it mean that you'd want to display it as e.g. "Hello Mr. Yo212"?

Comment: Hello, Yes that's right, with the value that I stored into an hidden item

Comment: There is a very detailed blog about sending emails from apex with a template: https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/creating-email-campaign-app-with-oracle-apex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you change body text to easily distinguish variables, e.g. `'<<FIRST_NAME>>'`.

Then, in a query, `replace` it with the (hidden) item value, such as

```
select replace(body, '<<FIRST_NAME>>', &P2_FIRST_NAME.) body
from template_table
```